# Странное поведение метода str.rstrip() в Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

Решая задачку из Яндекс.Лицея столкнулся с одной любопытной проблемой. Дело в том, что при попытке обрезать строку *"nikita_nikitin@untitled.py"* с помощью встроенного метода rstrip() получается не совсем корректный (с моей точки зрения) результат. При выполнении следующего отрывка:

```py
print('nikita_nikitin@untitled.py'.rstrip('@untitled.py'))
```

на выходе получается строка

```py
nikita_nik
```

в то время, как на выходе ожидалась строка "nikita_nikitin".

Так же замечу, что следующие команды работают более корректно:

```py
print('nikita_nikitin9@untitled.py'.rstrip('@untitled.py'))
print('nikita_nikitin@untitled.py'.rstrip('itin@untitled.py'))
```

На выходе получаем:

```
nikita_nikitin9
nikita_nik
```

Проверял только в Python 3.7, в качестве IDE - PyCharm.

В связи с этим вопрос:
**Чем все-таки вызвано такое поведение интерпретатора и как объясняется данная проблема?**

Comment: Это не строка! Это список символов, которые необходимо убрать с конца.

Comment: @nomnoms12 действительно... Я не додумался до такого, а матчасть плохо знаю, видимо. В любом случае спасибо, проблему я осознал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) по методу `str.rstrip([chars])` сказано:

> Return a copy of the string with trailing characters removed. The
>   chars argument is a string specifying the set of characters to be
>   removed. If omitted or `None`, the chars argument defaults to removing
>   whitespace. The chars argument is not a suffix; rather, all
>   combinations of its values are stripped:

Вольный перевод (частично):

> Возвращает копию строки с удаленными конечными символами. Аргумент
>   `chars` — это строка, указывающая набор удаляемых символов.

---

Простыми словами, будут удаляться все символы, до первого неподходящего.

В Вашем примере первый символ с конца, который не входит в коллекцию `@untitled.py` — это `k`. Всё остальное будет удалено.

Comment: Спасибо! Наперёд буду проверять себя и документацию, прежде чем идти задавать вопрос)